# Prove that there exist $w_1, \dots, w_m \in W$ such that no $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$ satisfies $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1, \dots ,m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $v_1,\dots, v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in $V$. Suppose also that $W \neq \{0\}$. Prove that there exist $w_1, \dots, w_m \in W$ such that no $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$ satisfies $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1, \dots ,m$.

---

If $v_1,\dots, v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in $V$, then we know for some $v_i$ in the list $v_i \in span(v_1, \dots, v_{i-1})$. We can also say that if $a_1v_1+\dots+a_mv_m=0$, then at least one $a_i \neq 0$.

However, I am stuck as to how to proceed further.

Answer (score 4):

By assumption, one of the $\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}\v v_1,\ldots,\v v_m$ is a linear combination of the others.  Say $\v v_l$ is a linear combination of the others,
$$\v v_l=\sum_{k\ne l}\alpha_k\v v_k\ .$$

Now choose $\v w_k=\v 0$ if $k\ne l$, and $\v w_l\ne\v0$: this is possible since $W\ne\{\v0\}$.  If $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$ then
$$T(\v v_l)=T\Bigl(\sum_{k\ne l}\alpha_k\v v_k\Bigr)
  =\sum_{k\ne l}\alpha_kT(\v v_k)\ .$$
Now if $T(\v v_k)=\v w_k$ for all $k$, this last equation says
$$\v w_l=\v0\ ,$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Fix some $1 \leq i \leq m$ such that $v_i = \sum_{j \neq i} \lambda_j v_j$ (such an $i$ exists by assumption). Choose $w_j \in W$ with $j \neq i$ arbitrary and choose $w_i \in W$ such that $w_i \neq \sum_{j \neq i} \lambda_{j} w_j$ (possible because $W \neq 0$). For every linear map $T \colon V \to W$ with $T v_j = w_j$ for every $j \neq i$ we have
$$
 T v_i
 = \sum_{j \neq i} \lambda_j T v_j
 = \sum_{j \neq i} \lambda w_j
 \neq w_i.
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Thoughts.* This exercise emphasizes the need for $V$ to be finite-dimensional in order for $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ to be defined uniquely by $Tv_k=w_k$, for $k=1,\ldots,m$.

---

*Proof.* First, choose a $w_1 \in W$ such that $w_1 \neq 0$. We can do this since we're assuming $W \neq \{0\}$. Next, choose a $w_2 \in W$ such that $w_2 \neq 0$ and the list $w_1, w_2$ is linearly independent. Continue to do this process until we have a list $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m$ that is linearly independent.

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ be any linear mapping. Suppose, for sake of contradiction, we define the following:

$$
Tv_1 = w_1, Tv_2 = w_2, \ldots, Tv_m = w_m
$$

Recall that the list $v_1, v_2 \ldots, v_m$ being linearly dependent implies that the list $Tv_1, Tv_2, \ldots, Tv_m$ is linearly dependent.

But then that would mean the list $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m$ is linearly dependent by our definition $Tv_k = w_k$, for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, m$, contradicting that $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m$ is linearly independent.

Thus, such a $T$ cannot exist when $v_1, v_2 \ldots, v_m$ are linearly dependent.